# Calculated column - extract only the number from alpha numeric string

Tags: calculated-column, number

I have a alpha numeric column which has values like "XGS000042210" or "XGS000836485".

How do I extract the number part alone omitting the zeros using calculated column?

For eg: If the column values are "XGS000042210" or "XGS000836485", using calculated column, how can i extract only the values "42210"  or "836485"?

Answer (score 3):

If you know it is always going to be 3 Letters at the start and the length is always same you can use  =INT(RIGHT(Column,9)).

Comment: Yes, the above formula did the trick, it removed all the zeroes. The output shows the numbers separated by commas. Is there a way I can display the output without commas?

Comment: =TEXT(INT(RIGHT(Column,9)),0) for reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c

Answer (score 0):

You can try  =TEXT(INT(RIGHT(Column,9)),"0") to convert it to text based.